# Enabling SASL authentication mechanisms in openLDAP using OLC

Tags: ldap, openldap, sasl

All of the information that I have been able to find about enabling SASL mechanisms for `openldap` still use the `slapd.conf` method while all modern LDAP directories have elected to use OLC over a static file.

Does anyone have information on how to add the `saslHost` paramaters to the OLC directory?  It also seems like I have more SASL mechanisms locally than I do through the frontend. How can I enable **plain** authentication via the frontend?

```
scadmin@ubuntu1604:~$ ldapsearch -x -H ldapi:/// -b "" -LLL -s base supportedSASLMechanisms
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: EXTERNAL
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
supportedSASLMechanisms: PLAIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: LOGIN

scadmin@ubuntu1604:~$ ldapsearch -x -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -b "" -LLL -s base supportedSASLMechanisms
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM

scadmin@ubuntu1604:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to enable the mechanisms using the following **ldif**:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcSaslHost
olcSaslHost: localhost
-
add: olcSaslSecProps
olcSaslSecProps: none
```

now my Supported SASL Mechanisms look like this:

```
scadmin@ldap-poc:~/ldap-assets$ ldapsearch -x -H ldapi:/// -b "" -LLL -s base supportedSASLMechanisms
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: EXTERNAL
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
supportedSASLMechanisms: PLAIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: LOGIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: ANONYMOUS

scadmin@ldap-poc:~/ldap-assets$ ldapsearch -x -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -b "" -LLL -s base supportedSASLMechanisms
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
supportedSASLMechanisms: PLAIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: LOGIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: ANONYMOUS
```